# Is there a way to upload files using the browsable API in Django REST framework?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I need to test an API that uploads a file. How do I do this from the browsable API. The browsable API page looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to upload files using this interface?

`views.py`:

```
class TrainingData(APIView):
"""
API for getting the training data
"""


def post(self, request,  format=None):
    """
    Receives the data in the form of a POST request
    """
    print request.data
    serialized = TrainingSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serialized.is_valid():
        file_obj = request.data['file']
        print "its working"
        return Response(status=204)

    return Response(serialized._errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`serializers.py`:

```
class TrainingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
"""
Serializer for the training data input
"""

uploaded_file = serializers.FileField(use_url=settings.BASE_DIR+"/api/uploaded_files/")
```

Comment: Use model serializer

Comment: That didn't change anything. The browsable API page still looks that same as shown in the picture in the question.

Comment: I used Generic Based views and it worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Django REST framework automatically generates an appropriate form in the browsable API only when using Generic Based views. Switching to Generic Based views solved my problem.

Using the following change I was able to get a file upload field

```
from rest_framework import generics  

class TrainingData(generics.CreateAPIView):
    "API for getting the training data"

    serializer_class = TrainingSerializer
```