# “detail”: “Method \”GET\“ not allowed.” Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I know this question was duplicate I am beginner in django I tried in all ways but not able to find solution
I was trying to upload a file and get a json response as ok using django rest framework

So far I tried is

views.py:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import FileSerializer

class FileView(APIView):
  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
  

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file_serializer.save()
      return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import FileView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/$', FileView.as_view(), name='file-upload'),
    url(r'^upload/<int:pk>/$', FileView.as_view(), name='file-upload'),
]
```

The error is:

Method /GET/ is not allowed

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @madhavi, you are getting this error for which endpoint? Also, I think you are using the postman or other API client to test the endpoints. Is it possible for you to share the request and response from it?

Comment: @VJMagar in this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/file/upload/  local one

Comment: @VJMagar not using postman just in the local server DRF i am getting this

Comment: Can you edit your question with the screenshot of the page?

Comment: @VJMagar I cant add the screenshot as I am new to stackoverflow with low points

Comment: I think it's expected behavior, as when are loading the page, a GET method is called. As the APIview doesn't have get method, it will show you that error. However, I belive you are still able to see the upload file option on the same page?

Comment: @VJMagar just same like this problem but change of view name and all https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57302570/detail-method-get-not-allowed-django-rest-framework

Comment: Ah. As mentioned in the llast comment, are you able to see the post option on the page?

Comment: @VJMagar plz see this image https://ibb.co/qRhhh1P

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32312084. However, I would recommend that you also get familiar with the postman or Insomnia app (https://insomnia.rest/) as it will help you in long go.

Comment: The reason I am suggesting that you start using such applications is that most of the API calls will be requested from various types of rest clients using in the frontend, mobile apps, etc.

Comment: @VJMagar yes I got post but I am getting the file 
"file": "/media/resume.pdf",
    "remark": "logo",
    "timestamp": "2021-04-05T07:40:20.776014Z"

but what I was trying to get the uploaded file content in json format not the file details is it possible could you please guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can have a look at your view.py file, You don't have any GET method and this is why it is not able to call the URL with GET request.